# How to detect a user close in AIR htmlView.stage.nativeWindow?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm writing a generic OAuth component (yes, it will be Open Source) and I want to detect if the user has clicked the close widget on the htmlView (or, more accurately, its browser window)

I have tried putting CLOSE listeners on both the htmlView and on the html.stage.nativeWindow to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this code might help

```
package com.bigspaceship.core.air
{
    // flash
    import flash.display.NativeWindow;
    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;    

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    public class NativeWindowManager extends EventDispatcher
    {
        private var _window            :NativeWindow;
        private var _isMainWindow    :Boolean;
        public var isQuitBlocked    :Boolean;

        public static const PROMPT    :String        = "windowQuitPrompt";

        public function NativeWindowManager($window:NativeWindow,$isMainWindow:Boolean = false):void
        {
            _window = $window;
            _isMainWindow = $isMainWindow;
            _window.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING,_windowOnClose,false,0,true);
        };

        public function get window():NativeWindow { return _window; };

        private function _mainWindowOnClose($evt:Event):void
        {
            $evt.preventDefault();

            if(isQuitBlocked) dispatchEvent(new Event(PROMPT));
            else close();
        };

        public function close():void
        {
            _window.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSING,_windowOnClose);

            if(_isMainWindow) NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
            else _window.close();

            _window = null;
        };
    };
};
```